# Kubernetes Prometheus metrics related to OOM score in order to prevent/monitor risks with OOMKilled

Tags: java, kubernetes, memory

I have Java Spring-Boot micro-service that is running inside Kubernetes.
JAVA_OPTS has values `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`, and container has configured memory as
`resources.requests.memory=1024Mi` and `resources.limits.memory=1024Mi`. I'm observing that periodically pods are restarted, and found Prometheus metrics by this service `kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{reason="OOMKilled"}`.

JVM Heap and Non-Heap metrics are far away from reaching the limit (heap does not exceed 350MB, and in sum heap and non-heap less than 600MB, it's based on `jvm_memory_used_bytes`), so this OOM does not relate to JVM OutOfMemoryError. Another metric from Kubernetes `container_memory_usage_bytes` is reaching limit of 1024MB frequently. I think need to increase properties `resources.requests.memory` and `resources.limits.memory` and it should resolve issue.

I see that there are OOM score based on which Kubernetes will restart pod with `OOMKilled` reasons:

> The OOM Killer uses an algorithm to determine which processes to
> target. It assigns a score, or ‘oom_score’, to each process based on
> factors such as the amount of memory it is using, how long it has been
> running, and its priority level. The process with the highest
> oom_score is selected for termination.

Are there any Prometheus metrics related to that `oom_score`? How can I monitor that to have automatic alerts? Or what other metrics could be monitored to fire alert if service is close to OOMKilled occurrence?

Comment: Note that modern JVMs can set the heap size based on the container memory limits; you should not need the `-Xmx -Xms` options.  If you're getting an OOMKilled status, then the process in the container has used more than its resource limits, or the node is overloaded; Kubernetes itself isn't aware of the JVM or its various memory pools.

Comment: looks like JVM works fine in that case with current configs, and indeed we reaching memory limit based on metric `container_memory_usage_bytes`